# JSONKit objectFromJSONString return nil when contents of character %EF%BF%BF in my jsonstring

Tags: ios

```
+ (void)testResponseStr
{
NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"error_json" ofType:@"txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSDictionary *destDic = [responseString objectFromJSONString];
NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
if (destDic) {
    NSLog(@"success");
}else{
    NSLog(@"error"); 
}
}
```

I am trying to parse a json string which is gotten from server, but when the the json string contents of charactor "" , the "destDic" from "objectFromJSONString" will be nil. Why? How do i fix the bug in JSONKit.

string in error_json.txt:

```
{"result":{"hasMore":true,"newestWorksList":[{"hasLiked":false,"hasCollected":false,"tlName":"No smoking","likeCount":1,"title":"No smoking","authorNickname":"","commentCount":0,"uid":"69nbNm","createTime":1453539369000,"id":2546522,"createTimeStr":"2016.01.23","tlIsUserUpload":false}]},"code":0}
```

Comment: Try using NSJSONSerialization

NSDictionary * destDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

NSString *responseString = [responseString 
   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"" withString:@""];

This is not solid solution but may be work for you for now

Comment: Thank you, Sachin Nikumbh, it works for this character, but if i get another character like this from server, It would not be parsed by JSONKit again. Do you know some other IOS JSON parse tools which is better than JSONKit?